# Timer event in web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have created a timer event try to running in the background of my web api, I found it works fine when I debugger on local dev machine. However, The timer does not work when I added them to IIS on server. It stops after the first web request finishes( I tested it by writing some text into log files, it seems stopped after a few triggers, once the web request completed)
Here is some example code.

```
void refreshTimeStart()
    {
        refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TIMER_INTERVAL"]));
        refreshTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(connectionResetEvent);
        refreshTimer.AutoReset = true;
        refreshTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
void connectionResetEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        testIndex = testIndex + 1;
        WriteToFile(testIndex);
               }
static void WriteToFile(int i)
     {
         string text = "This start trigged. ";
         System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Projects\abc" + i.ToString() + ".txt", text);
     }
```

Any idea of how to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked a long time ago but here's an answer anyway.

First of all, using a timer in a Web API is probably not the best idea. A windows service would be more appropriate. That being said, your problem must come from two issues:

1. a Web API awaits a request and only initializes after the first request. So you'll have to initiate a request for your timer to start.
2. the default settings of application pools in IIS have a timeout. So even if you initialize the Web API, the application pool will terminate after the timeout period has elapsed. You could disable the timeout.